# What does "expression must have class type" error mean?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrayTest[512];
    int size = arrayTest.size();
    for(int a = 0;a<size;a++)
    {
         //stuff will go here
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here becuase the plan is to just fill the array with some numbers

Answer (score 10):

Do this:

```
int arrayTest[512];
int size = sizeof(arrayTest)/sizeof(*arrayTest);
```

C-style arrays don't have member function. They don't have any notion of class.

Anyway, **better** use `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int,512> arrayTest;
int size = arrayTest.size();   //this line is exactly same as you wrote!
```

which looks like what you wanted. Now you can use index `i` to access elements of `arrayTest` as `arrayTest[i]` where `i` can vary from `0` to `size-1` (inclusive).

Comment: While `sizeof(*arrayTest)` is intriguingly smart, it's not easy to understand if you don't know that a C style array `T[N]` decays to a pointer `T *` or that `sizeof` expressions are not evaluated.

Comment: @nijansen: One who doesn't know will know soon if he continues exploring the language. :-)

Comment: Actually I agree with nijansen... I'd rather recomment (to the novice) refactoring into `const int SIZE = 512; int arrayTest[SIZE];`... which is safer (user won't assume that the C style trick will work with everything that *feels* like an array). Alternatively provide a typesafe way of getting the array size...

Comment: For MSVC _countof macro could be much easier for novice

Answer (score 6):

`arrayTest` is not a class or struct but an array and it does not have member functions, in this case this will get your the size of the array:

```
size_t size = sizeof(arrayTest)/sizeof(int);
```

although if your compiler supports *C++11* than using [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) would be better:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int,512> arrayTest ;
size_t size = arrayTest.size() ;
```

as the document linked above shows you can also use range for loop to iterate over the elements of a *std::array*:

```
for( auto &elem : arrayTest )
{
   //Some operation here
}
```

Comment: It is not clear if c++11 for feature can be used, this may confuse

Comment: @Andrey that is why I showed both methods but that is fair enough, I added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays don't have members. You have to use something like:

```
int size = sizeof(arrayTest) / sizeof(arrayTest[0]);
```

Better yet, if you must work with normal arrays instead of `std::array`, use a helper function. This also has the advantage of not breaking when you attempt it on a pointer instead of an array:

```
template<int N, typename T> int array_size(T (&)[N]) {return N;}

int size = array_size(arrayTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with arrays you can define your getArraySize function:

```
template <typename T,unsigned S> 
inline unsigned getArraySize(const T (&v)[S]) { return S; }
```

seen here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/33669/#msg181103

std::array remains the better solution.