# Why am I receiving "Expression must have a class type" error? (C++)

Tags: c++

`wDeck`, in the code below is giving me an **`"expression must have a class type"`** error. I've already had `wDeck` clarified in most of the other code `void fillDeck(Card* wDeck, void shuffle(Card* wDeck), void deal( Card wDeck[][13]))`

I don't understand it

I haven't tried much since I only have basic knowledge of C++

I use Visual Studio 2019, Enterprise

````cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

struct Card {
    char *face;
    char *suit;
};

void shuffle(int[][13]);
void deal(const int[][13], const char* [], const char* []);
void fillDeck(Card*, char* [], char* []);


int main() {
    const char* suit[4] =
    { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
    const char* face[13] =
    {
        "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
    int deck[4][13] = { 0 };

    srand(time(0));

    shuffle(deck);
    deal(deck, face, suit);

    return 0;
}

void fillDeck(Card* wDeck, char* wFace[], char* wSuit[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        wDeck[i].face = wFace[i % 13];
        wDeck[i].suit = wSuit[i / 13];
    }
}

void shuffle(Card* wDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        int j = rand() % 52;
        Card temp = wDeck[i];
        wDeck[i] = wDeck[j];
        wDeck[j] = temp;
    }
}

void deal( Card wDeck[][13])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            cout << setiosflags(ios::right)
            <<setw(5) << wDeck[ i ].face << " of "
            <<setiosflags(ios::left)
            <<setw(8) << wDeck[ i ].suit
            <<( ( i + 1 ) % 2 ? '\t': '\n' );
    }```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "expression must have class type" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965212/what-does-expression-must-have-class-type-error-mean)

Comment: read Shafik Yaghmour's answer

Comment: Your prototype is mis-matched. Try putting Card in the prototype for `deal` and `shuffle` where it is down below.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: You have this `Card wDeck[][13]` and then are trying to treat `wDeck` as if it were a 1d 52-element array. You cannot have it both ways. It is either `[4][13]` or `[52]`, and these are not compatible or intetchangeable or anything like that.

Comment: My compiler says `55:37: error: request for member 'face' in '*(wDeck + ((sizetype)(((long unsigned int)i) * 208)))', which is of non-class type 'Card [13]'    55 |             <<setw(5) << wDeck[ i ].face << " of "` `   Giving the whole error message makes things  a lot easier.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah  what compiler do you have, i have visual studio 2019 enterprise and it showed the same error he mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

In this  code

```
    void deal( Card wDeck[][13])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            cout << setiosflags(ios::right)
            <<setw(5) << wDeck[ i ].face << " of "
            <<setiosflags(ios::left)
            <<setw(8) << wDeck[ i ].suit
            <<( ( i + 1 ) % 2 ? '\t': '\n' );
    }
```

you defined 
 `wDeck[][13]` as a multi-dimensional array
then you tried to access it as a 1 dimensional array

```
 wDeck[ i ]
```

what this does is the following:

In the first iteration the result of `wDeck[ 0 ]` is another array, in your case it has 13 elements
wDeck[i] is not a class or a struct, it is an array hence it does not have member functions.

it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965212/what-does-expression-must-have-class-type-error-mean)
in your code, you can substitute `arrayTest` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965212/what-does-expression-must-have-class-type-error-mean) with  `wDeck[i]` in your code, then you can see how you both did the same mistake, so now you are trying to access an array of 13 element using struct member pointer. hence you get the same error

what you need is use nested loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
 for (int j =0 ; j<13 ;j++)
{
 cout << setiosflags(ios::right)
            <<setw(5) << wDeck[ i ][j].face << " of "
            <<setiosflags(ios::left)
            <<setw(8) << wDeck[ i ][j].suit
            <<( ( i + 1 ) % 2 ? '\t': '\n' );
}
}
```

What this code does is, it iterates over the first layer of the array wDeck[](i think you defined this array as 4 after reading your code), the result will be an array of the second layer(i can see you defined it as 13), then you iterate over the second layer of the array and then you get an object of type Card  where you can use it's members and functions if it has any

I think you need to learn more about multi-dimensional array and nested loop possibly

excuse my English